# Is there some way in Pandas to aggregate rows by one column and sort by another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*Disclaimer: it`s my first question, fell little akward :/*

I have DataFrame that have two columns: `title` and `val`:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "title": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"],
...         "val": [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 5],
...     }
... )
>>> df
  title  val
0     a    1
1     a    4
2     a    3
3     b    4
4     b    5
5     b    6
6     c    2
7     c    4
8     c    5
```

I would like to aggregate rows in clusters with same `title` and then sort that clusters by descending of maximum `val` that they have. If maximum `val` equals, then sort clusters by `title` alphabetically. The rows in the clusters must be sort descending by `val`.

I know, I can do it in long way, like:

```
>>> df.loc[:,'max_value']=df.groupby('title', as_index=False).transform(max) 
>>> df
  title  val  max_value
0     a    1          4
1     a    4          4
2     a    3          4
3     b    4          6
4     b    5          6
5     b    6          6
6     c    2          5
7     c    4          5
8     c    5          5
>>> df.sort_values(['max_value','title', 'val'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
>>> df.drop(columns='max_value', inplace=True)
>>> df
  title  val
5     b    6
4     b    5
3     b    4
8     c    5
7     c    4
6     c    2
1     a    4
2     a    3
0     a    1
```

But will some shortcut have place there?

Comment: You don't need max_value. sort_values takes care of that, just pass the two columns and the other parameters

Comment: This was a great first question in that you provided: 1) good title, 2) data, 3) desired result, and 4) code you tried, thus my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

There is sorting by multiple columns, so created helper column `new` used for sorting:

```
df = df.loc[df.assign(a = df.groupby('title', as_index=False).transform(max))
              .sort_values(['a','title', 'val'], ascending=False).index]
print (df)
  title  val
5     b    6
4     b    5
3     b    4
8     c    5
7     c    4
6     c    2
1     a    4
2     a    3
0     a    1
```